# How can I make a .txt file from Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
databaseReference.child("chat").child(chatName).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
  {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
    {
       for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
       {
         Log.d("ChatActivity", "ValueEventListener : "+chatName + snapshot.getValue() + "\n");
       }
  }
```

When I run Log.d

```
2019-11-26 16:23:32.928 2599-2599/com.test.myapplication D/ChatActivity: ValueEventListener : TESTCHAT{time= AM 7:23, message=test1, userName=USER1}
2019-11-26 16:23:32.928 2599-2599/com.test.myapplication D/ChatActivity: ValueEventListener : TESTCHAT{time= AM 7:23, message=test2, userName=USER1}
```

I want to make txt file which i get from 'Firebase database chat logs' 
What should I do?

Comment: What exactly do you want to have in your txt file?

Comment: It seems you are using Java as a language, simply create a new file using Java File APIs and write your data into that. Let me know if you want a code to write something into a .txt file.

Comment: i wnat to make txt file into firebase chat logs.
i think getting chat logs code is "snapshot.getValue()".

Answer (score 0):

To create a txt file then inside the for loop do the following:

```
try {
  File logTxt = new File("log.txt");
  FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(logTxt);
  OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);    
  Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
  w.write(snapshot.getValue(String.class));
  w.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println("Problem writing to the file log.txt");
}
```

Initialize a new instance of File and give it the path of the txt file that you want to create, then use the `BufferedWriter` to write the `snapshot` data to the file.

Comment: I tried that code, but there's some problem. I got this Error log "W/System.err: Problem writing to the file log.txt"

Comment: do `System.err.println(e);` and tell me what it will output

Comment: I cant find anywhere log.txt file on my Virtual device..... what should i do now ?

Comment: u should put the path here `File("log.txt")` example put it in localdisk d

Comment: What error are you getting? What did you get in System.err.println(e)?